# Which ICC model for comparing one rater vs. several raters?

Tags: agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I'm analysing a dataset in which a diagnostic instrument has been administered to a sample of roughly 30 patients. The instrument yields dichotomous scores (presence or absence of diagnosis) as well as interval scores (sum total of symptoms present). The instrument was administered and assessed by four raters who assessed roughly the same amount of patients each. Then I listened to a recording of the instrument being administered and assessed all the patients.

I'm now looking to calculate the intraclass correlation coefficient, and am wondering which model to use. The terminology is a little confusing to me. As far as I've been able to tell, it seems there are three alternatives, I'm not sure which would be the most appropriate:

a) Using a two-way, mixed effects model, computing different coefficients for me vs. clinician 1, me vs. clinician 2, etc., and then reporting these individually, or possibly aggregating them into a composite figure?

b) Basically ignoring the fact that there were several raters and treating the sample as though it were just one experienced clinician vs. me, thus using the two-way, mixed effects model on the whole sample?

c) Computing the coefficient using the one-way, random effects model or the two-way, random effects model. Maybe this is the way to go? But the way I understand it, this makes the assumption that the sets of raters were randomly selected -- which is not really true, as my presence is a constant even as the other raters changed between subjects.

I'm sure there are lots of nuances and important methodological assumptions that I'm not quite grasping here, and would be very grateful for any and all pointers.

I've been relying on Koo and Li's article from 2016 to guide me along so far:  https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.jcm.2016.02.012